# How to enable AllowTcpForwarding in Jelastic?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, jelastic

It seems that in Jelastic version 5.8 onward `AllowTcpForwarding` is set to `no` by default, which means that SSH port forwarding is not possible https://docs.jelastic.com/release-notes-58/#ssh-security.

What is the recommended way to set `AllowTcpForwarding` to `yes` for an environment?

Comment: To edit this setting in the sshd_config file, the root rights are needed. Please, contact your Hosting Provider and ask to edit this setting for your environment(s). Our colleagues would gladly assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the best way is to talk to your Jelastic hosting provider to see if they can provide you with a decent solution.

We've just published an [add-on (JPS)](https://github.com/layershift/jps-sshtun/blob/master/sshtun.jps) for this case which you're welcome to use at whichever your provider may be.

[image: Import JPS from URL]

The basic idea is that having `AllowTcpForwarding` enabled by default is a potential security risk in that you may construct security rules (e.g. firewall) for other parts of your topology on the assumption that only local traffic can be there. Although something of an edge case, there's a potential for this assumption to be exploited in order to give access to some application or port that should not be permitted.

However, if you're aware of the risks and only enable this functionality where you have a specific need for it (rather than the old default of indiscriminately enabled everywhere), it should be safe to enable; either manually on request to your Jelastic hosting provider, or via the add-on that I've linked to.

The linked add-on has an option to disable as well, so you can easily flick it on/off on-demand if you wish.

Comment: Looks great. How could I modify the script so that it would work on any node type, not just sqldb?

Comment: You can replace targetNodes on line 15, but can you describe the use case? We only met this request in the context of desktop app for database admin

Comment: I want to use it for a JavaEngine environment on which I'm running a Clojure web app. With Clojure, you can connect your local editor to a REPL on the live server and hotpatch the running app, which is great for instant feedback during developing and debugging. Normally you do this through an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. You can find possible options in the docs at https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/selecting-containers/

Comment: For future readers: Replace `sqldb` with `cp` in the `targetNodes:` section of the JPS addon (https://github.com/layershift/jps-sshtun/blob/master/sshtun.jps) if you want to use it for JavaEngine or other compute-type nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to get port forwarding working even when `AllowTcpForwarding` is set to false is to use the [mutagen network forwarding](https://mutagen.io/documentation/forwarding) tool instead of SSH port forwarding.

Example

```
mutagen forward create --name=my-web-app-repl tcp:localhost:7001 XXXX-XXXX@gate.mircloud.host:3022:tcp::7001
```